# Display array of an object in separate cards

Tags: html, angular

I want to achieve the same thing similar to the below picture. The sample code snippet in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qsghvd?file=src/app/app.component.html) develop in Angular shows what I am able to achieve so far.

[image: Chat Message]

Comment: I think your question is too broad. There are multiple ways to accomplish that but I am guessing you have some more solid requirements based on the payload. In any case, CSS can be used to accomplish what you need

Comment: What do you mean by "more solid requirements based on the payload" please?

Comment: I see you have a different color on the UI and also some indentation. At the same time, in your component, you have a data structure that probably contains all the data you need to make a decision on how to show the message. That is the kind of requirements/specifications I am talking about, with that info I will be able to better help you

Comment: Code should be included in the question so its single source of truth

Comment: Also how to distinguish from the sender and receiver in your data

Comment: I get you @orlaqp. There is the stack blitz specifying all the data there is for the code.

Comment: The distinction is from the extranet values 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the card with to a value which is less than 100%, and based on the user, add a margin to the left or the right.

You can use `[ngClass]` bootstrap utility class `ml-auto` or `mr-auto` for this.

app.component.css

```css
.chat-box {
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 scroll">
    <div class="card chat-box" *ngFor="let chatMassage of allChat; let i = index "
        [ngClass]="(chatMassage.extranet === 1 && i !== 0) ? 'mr-auto' : 'ml-auto'">
        <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white">

            <span class="font-weight-bold text-left float-left mr-4" *ngIf=" chatMassage.extranet === 1 && i !== 0">  User 1  / {{chatMassage.created | date:'shortTime'}} </span>
            <span class="font-weight-bold text-right float-right pl-5" *ngIf=" chatMassage.extranet === 0 && i !== 0">  User 2 {{chatMassage.created | date:'shortTime'}} </span>

        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">{{chatMassage.message}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example can be found [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64599407?file=src/app/app.component.html)